# How to check if page exists using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Javascript and i want check if a page/url (of another domain exist)

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'http://google.com',
success: function() {
        alert('1');
},
error: function() {
        alert('0');
}
});
```

it show me this **error**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localads-4u.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

**Note** : the tested script is online

Comment: Have you googled that error? Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/20035101/870729

Comment: Your doing this on a file:// .... set up a localhost, so you dont get the Acess Alow Control Origin.. Also why ask this.. there are a ton of questions about this.

Comment: @cale_b Present Question is different where current Question asks how to determine if resource is available, not how to also access the resource. Linked page _"I am trying to do authorization using JavaScript"_ , current page _"I'm using Javascript and i want check if a page/url (of another domain exist)"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using Javascript and i want check if a page/url (of another domain
>   exist)

If only requirement is to check if the external resource is available, one possible workaround for `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` response from `AJAX` is to instead request `.html` `document` or url at `src` of `<img>` element. Check `onerror` handler for `GET http://example.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(e) {
  console.log(this, this.src)
}

img.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log(e, this)
};

img.src = "http://example.com";
```

Comment: Ohh thanks bro :) that's what I need .. 
Please how can I make an if condition (if exist \do something/ else \do another thing/ ) ?
Thanks again

Comment: @hassenzouari _"how can I make an if condition (if exist \do something/ else \do another thing/ ) ?"_ ? Check whether `onload` or `onerror` is called

Comment: Like this if(img.onerror){//do something} ? Thaks again

Comment: No, use the `onload` or `onerror` handlers. If resource is available at `onerror` try checking for `console` for `GET http://example.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error

Comment: Yeah I see this error when the link isn't correct .. but i don't understand you very well ,, please can you update the Comment code ? 
Thanks

Comment: `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` appears to be chrome / chromium internal error.

Comment: At chrome / chromium you could create an extension which parsed `.har` entries for `content.size` of last entry